# keyboardWillShow Notification not called immediately after becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented `keyboardWillShow:` and `keyboardWillHide:` notifications. I am registering the notifications and they work perfectly after directly touching the screen on the `UITextField`, but there's a problem. In my `viewDidLoad` right after registering the notifications I'm calling `becomeFirstResponder`. The keyboard pops up but the `keyboardWillShow:` is not getting called (as mentioned, only the first time. It seems like there's a delay from the time you call the function to register the notification and the time it is actually registered, and I shouldn't delay the execution of `becomeFirstResponder`). Any ideas?

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Show")
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
        var contentInset: UIEdgeInsets = self.tv_main.contentInset
        contentInset.bottom = keyboardSize.height
        self.tv_main.contentInset = contentInset
        let indexpath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        self.tv_main.scrollToRow(at: indexpath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Hide")
    if let _ = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.tv_main.contentInset = contentInset

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tv_main.delegate = self
    tv_main.dataSource = self
    tf_search.delegate = self
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    self.tf_search.becomeFirstResponder()
    if let placeholder = tf_search.placeholder {
        tf_search.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholder, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `becomeFirstResponder` in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Thanks. I used `viewWilAppear`, didn't work; but `viewDidAppear` worked.